# Separate materials in an instancedMesh react three fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I essentially have a bunch of geometries that I need to display unique and updating text.

The approach I've been using to display the text is using a canvas material which(along with the mesh position) is constantly updated in a `useFrame`.

However, the only way I've been able to get the texture to work is as follows, and all geometries are obviously sharing it.

```
<instancedMesh ref={meshRef} args={[null, null, intervalData.length]}>
  <circleBufferGeometry args={[sizes.radius ?? 0.6, sizes.segments ?? 48]}>
    <instancedBufferAttribute attachObject={['attributes', 'color']} args={[colorArray, 3]} />
  </circleBufferGeometry>
  <meshStandardMaterial vertexColors={THREE.VertexColors} map={texture}/>
</instancedMesh>
```

What would be the way to set the textures per instance? Is there somewhere I can store an array of textures and assign them to the mesh?

Answer (score 0):

Probably pretty late for you, but maybe if someone else is stuck with same question. I have solved this like this https://codesandbox.io/s/instancedmesh-with-different-textures-forked-iy5xh?file=/src/App.js
Though I am passing each texture separately, it has down side that you can only pass 16 textures to single shader, so maybe you'll have to use texture atlas (basically single texture composed of multiple texture and you also pass couple of more attributes to crop the particular texture part from whole texture)

Answer (score -2):

Probably any performance boost from InstancedMesh would be surpassed by using a Sprite, not to mention more useful.